# Is there a way to list files in an FTP directory that only anonymous has access to?

Tags: ftp, directory, anonymous, directory-listing

Admittedly this question I'm asking is just to assist me in an argument I've been scheduled to have with a client.

Our Dev's who reside in another country have an FTP server which has mostly full public access available to all anonymous users, this to simplify the acquisition of new documents and updates for users of the application.

One directory in specific, let's call it updates, actually houses all the new updates but does not grant a directory list to anonymous users due to Access restrictions, so if you try to list the files in the directory using an FTP client, you're met with the generic response:

**550 Access is denied.
Failed to retrieve directory listing**

However, if you have the exact URL for a file available to the anonymous users in that directory e.g. **ftp://ftp.company.com/updates/latest_update_1.zip** you can very easily download that file without issue.

My question comes in that I have a client who is somehow monitoring that directory as an anonymous user and knows when a new file (which anonymous has access to) becomes available in that directory and then immediately downloads it. This directly affects their application as often times files are dropped there by Devs during QA and they're not officially available as we've not yet sent out notice of the change log and URL.

So my question is, how exactly is this client doing this? How is he able to list files that anonymous has access to, in a directory which does not list it's files to anonymous users?

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: And of course, the client cannot list a directory, if the listing is restricted by the server. So if the client can list the directory, the server configuration is different than what you think. The client possibly uses a non-anonymous access. The the client has higher privileges granted e.g. based on its IP address.